# status of 413 (Payload Too Large) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload a large file getting this error :

> Warning:  POST Content-Length of 11651349 bytes exceeds the limit
> of 8388608 bytes in **Unknown** on line **0**
>  {
> "message": "",
> "exception": "Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException",
> "file": "C:\wamp64\www\uba-nectar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php",
> "line": 24,
> "trace": [
> {
> "file": "C:\wamp64\www\uba-nectar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",
> "line": 167,

Modified these values in php.ini file of my local system (WAMP server)

```
upload_max_filesize = 950M
```

Size of file is 11 mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed modifying the value `post_max_size` in the php.ini file. Change it to 950M to have posts accept the larger memory buffer. Restart Apache and the new value will take effect.

Comment: updated this value post_max_size = 950M but still getting error

Comment: Did you restart apache? Also do you have multiple php versions?

Comment: yes i have mutliplte php version and restarted apache also

Comment: Please load the phpinfo() function on your site(modify a controller to echo out the function) to see which version of php you're using. If the version is different, please update that version and restart apache.